# Trying to use an if-else statement to make an error message pop up if a negative number is entered or if the amount entered is too high

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I'm trying to do this assignment where we need to modify code we submitted for an assignment weeks ago to now include error validation through if-else statements. The modified code is supposed to make it to where if you enter a negative value for the amount of things you want to order, it will display an error message. An error message would also be displayed if you order an amount that is beyond the maximum value. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ2al.png)

The code I used for the assignment a few weeks ago is below, but my main issue is I am unsure of how to input the if-else statements that will enable the error messages to pop up if I was to enter the negative numbers or amounts that exceed the maximum value. I could really use the help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AndreLunchShop {

    // declaring the constants and their prices
    private static final double COST_PER_SODA = 1;   
    private static final double COST_PER_SANDWICH = 3;   
    private static final double COST_PER_BANANA = 0.5;   
    private static final double TAX_PERCENT = 0.07;   

    // creating the title frame and the panel to hold all the components within
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Andre's Lunch Shop");      
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));    

        // creating the panel, label, and text field for the cost of a soda based on user input
        JPanel sodaSubPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));   
        JLabel sodaNameLabel = new JLabel("Soda");  
        JLabel sodaCostLabel = new JLabel("$1 per Soda");  
        JTextField nSodasField = new JTextField(10);
 
        // adding the panel, label, and text field to the sub panel
        sodaSubPanel.add(sodaNameLabel);    
        sodaSubPanel.add(sodaCostLabel);    
        sodaSubPanel.add(nSodasField);    
    
        // creating the panel, label, and text field for the cost of a sandwich based on user input
        JPanel sandwichSubPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));   
        JLabel sandwichNameLabel = new JLabel("Sandwich");  
        JLabel sandwichCostLabel = new JLabel("$3 per Sandwich");  
        JTextField nSandwichesField = new JTextField(10);
   
        // adding the panel, label, and text field to the sub panel
        sandwichSubPanel.add(sandwichNameLabel);    
        sandwichSubPanel.add(sandwichCostLabel);    
        sandwichSubPanel.add(nSandwichesField);    
    
        // creating the panel, label, and text field for the cost of a banana based on user input
        JPanel bananaSubPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));   
        JLabel bananaNameLabel = new JLabel("Banana");  
        JLabel bananaCostLabel = new JLabel("$0.50 per Banana");  
        JTextField nBananasField = new JTextField(10);  
  
        // adding the panel, label, and text field to the sub panel
        bananaSubPanel.add(bananaNameLabel);    
        bananaSubPanel.add(bananaCostLabel);    
        bananaSubPanel.add(nBananasField);    

        // creating a sub panel with a button to calculate the order
        JPanel buttonSubPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));   
        JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate"); 

        // adding the "Calculate" button to the sub panel
        buttonSubPanel.add(calculateButton);    

        // creating a sub panel with an uneditable text area and border to display order total
        JPanel orderTotalSubPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));   
        JTextArea orderTotalArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);    
        orderTotalArea.setEditable(false);  
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your Order Total");    
        orderTotalArea.setBorder(border);   
    
        // adds text area to the order total
        orderTotalSubPanel.add(orderTotalArea);    

        // adds all the sub panels to the main panel
        mainPanel.add(sodaSubPanel);  
        mainPanel.add(sandwichSubPanel);  
        mainPanel.add(bananaSubPanel);  
        mainPanel.add(buttonSubPanel);  
        mainPanel.add(orderTotalSubPanel);  

        // adds the main panel to the mainframe
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);   

        // sets the initial size of the mainframe and the ability to close properly
        mainFrame.setSize(380, 370);                    
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                      
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);                                

        calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           
                if(nSodasField.getText().equals("") || nSandwichesField.getText().equals("") || nBananasField.getText().equals("")) {
              
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter details for all the food items!");
                return;
                }
                int nSodas = Integer.parseInt(nSodasField.getText().trim());    
                int nSandwiches = Integer.parseInt(nSandwichesField.getText().trim());    
                int nBananas = Integer.parseInt(nBananasField.getText().trim());    
                // get the number of sodas, sandwiches, and bananas to parse into integers
          
                // calculates the order subtotal, the tax, and the order total after applying the 7% tax
                double orderSubTotal = (nSodas * COST_PER_SODA) + (nSandwiches * COST_PER_SANDWICH) + (nBananas * COST_PER_BANANA);    
                double tax = (orderSubTotal * TAX_PERCENT); 
                double orderTotal = (orderSubTotal + tax);  
           
                String orderString = "WELCOME TO THE SHOP:\n" +
                    "-------------------------------------\n" +
                    "Soda: " + nSodas + "\nSandwich: " + nSandwiches + "\nBananas: " + nBananas + "\n" +
                    "====================\n" +
                    "Order Sub-total: $" + String.format("%.2f", orderSubTotal) + "\n" +
                    "Tax at 7%: $" + String.format("%.2f", tax) + "\n" +
                    "Order Total: $" + String.format("%.2f", orderTotal) + "\nThank You!";
                    
            // order detail string is set to the text area
            orderTotalArea.setText(orderString);    
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You would do that by intervening in the `actionPerformed` code where you do the parsing of entered numbers. A `JOptionPane` could be used for errors

Comment: @g00se Yeah I was trying to do a JOptionPane for that but I was doing it in the wrong code block, thanks for the tip,

Comment: I don't see any effort of _if you enter a negative value for the amount of things you want to order, it will display an error message_ nor the second part of the title .. go ahead and give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first comment in calculateButton.addActionListener(), add the if/else like this:

```
if(nSodas > 0 && nSandwiches > 0 && nBanannas > 0) {
//calculate the subtotal and return the total.
} else {
//display error
}
```